# Sort table using Comparator which "pins" items at top

Tags: java, logic, comparator

I have a custom table using a Comparator to sort items by column. I want to "pin" certain items to top, regardless of current sorting (asc/desc). Besides "normal" items (***C***), which are compared as usual, I also have one special item (**A**) which must always be at the top of table and N "favorite" items (***B***), which must be after **A** and before ***C*** and their order is not important (but I also tried "subsorting" them based on their numeric value).

Here is a representation of what my table should look like no matter what is current sorting (only ***C*** items should ever be sorted):

```
A (always present on top)
B (isFavorite)
B (isFavorite)
C (these items are sorted normally)
C
...
C
```

Here is my comparator which is not working properly. Sometimes ***A*** is after ***B*** or I even get `Comparator violates general contract` exception.

```
private class CustomOrderAwareComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        // isA() is always true only for one item
        if(o1.isA() && o2.isA())
            return 0;
        else if(o1.isA())
            return table.getSortedOrder() == DESCENDING ? 1 : -1;

        // isB() can be true for multiple items
        if(o1.isB() && o2.isB()))
            return 0;
        else if(o1.isB())
            return table.getSortedOrder() == DESCENDING ? 1 : -1;

        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any input on what I am missing here. Thanks!

Comment: is it that there's a `else if` condition missing for `o2.isA()`

Comment: what is `e2`, copy&paste error? and more important, what happens if `o2` is `A`? or `B`? (for ordering when both are `A` (or `B`) just return the result from `compareTo` instead of zero)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes, I fixed the example. A is guaranteed to be only one. Any item set will always have just one A.

Comment: does not answer "what if `o2` is `A`?" - you  are not testing the case that `o2` (alone) is that one `A` element, you are only checking `o1` - you need something like `if (o2,isA()) return ...` {same for `if (o2.isB()) ...`}

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thanks, this helped! I added these checks and it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think after `else if (o1.isA()) return...` you also need `else if (o2.isA()) return table.getSortedOrder() == DESCENDING ? -1 : 1;`. Do the same kind of thing for `B`. Otherwise some of the As and some of the Bs may fall through to the `getValue()` check.

That might fix the general contract violation, but you may need to update your `equals` method to match the behavior of `compare`.

Comment: actually no `else` is needed since `return`ing in each `if` block

Comment: Yes, adding these two `else if` helped and is now working properly. Thank you! Not sure if Ishould still override `equals` now, since everything is already working? What case would it resolve?

Comment: Cool. The contract error probably happened when a collection using the comparator for sorting noticed that the equals method wasn't consistent with the compare method. The typical equals method generated by an IDE most likely is consistent with your fixed compare method.